# JS tools to Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am migrating my `Ionic1` project to `Ionic2` these days. Fun!
One hurdle right now is to migrate a long list of tool functions written in JS such as `CmToFeet` / `InchesToCM` / `FarenheitToCelsius` to the Ionic2 project.
I do not know how to properly include these files in the project and make sure they will be considered for the build process. Can I just include them in the `index.html` and they automatically will be available? Do I need to do more?
Any tips?

Comment: from my understanding, replicating your ionic1 project with a newly created ionic2 project will be more faster / easier and saves u from running in to walls. Coz from ionic1 -> ionic2 its a huge structural change and when u add typescript to the mix its worse. But that might be only me :)

Comment: But this has nothing to do with his question ;)  To include external javascript you could just include it in your `index.html` and if it exports a certain member, you can declare it underneath your `import ...` but above your `@Component` with `declare var CmToFeet: any;` for example

Comment: @sameera207 - I would be happy to avoid all that TS stuff, but the native ionic2 features are much better. Yes, I am replicating the project, but the tool library I thought to keep.

Comment: @ivaro18 - Can you please post a link to an example what you mean? Do I have to extend my JS code with the decorators? Can you please add a link to an example what you mean? That would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to do that would be to treat it just as *another asset*. To do so, you can create a folder in `src/assets/scripts`, put those js files there and then add the script tag in your `index.html` file like this:

```
<script src="assets/scripts/jsFileName.js"></script>
```

If you used to call those functions by doing something like `CmToFeet.methodName()`, now you will need to declare `CmToFeet` variable to prevent typescript errors

```
import {... } from '...';

declare var CmToFeet: any; // <- Like this

@Component({
    selector:'my-page',
    templateUrl: 'my-page.html',
})
export class MyPage {

  // ...

}
```

Please notice that by doing things like this, the autocomplete features won't work since it's declared as of type `any`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. This way they would be automatically added to the build process. The JS files are just a loose collection of functions, no structure. Hence I am calling them as `cmToFeet()` or `feetToCM()`, no leading `ModuleName`.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)